# Evaluate $\min_{a,b \in [-1,1]}\max_{x\in [-1,1]} \ |(x-a)(x-b)|$

Tags: interpolation, maxima-minima

> Evaluate $\min_{a,b \in [-1,1]}\max_{x\in [-1,1]}|(x-a)(x-b)|$.

Find **maximas** of $|(x-a)(x-b)|$  over $[-1,1]$.
So I calculated the derivative and I finally found that this optimisation problem was the following : 
$$\min_{a,b \in [-1;1]} \max \left \{ \frac{1}{4}(a-b)^{2},(1+a)(1+b),(1-a)(1-b) \right \}$$

And now they ask me to resolve this using this graphic :

[image: optimisation graphic]

And here I have no idea how to proceed.Is the **minimum** at the *4 corners* or is it at the **intersection** of the *3 planes* ?
Thanks

Comment: There are three variables $x$, $a$, $b$. It is unclear in which order mins or maxes are taken over which variables. What is the range of $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the graph the minimum is along the line $a+b=0$, one of the diagonals of the square $[-1,1]^2$.
Hence, for $a,b\in [-1,1]$,
$$\max \left \{ \frac{1}{4}(a-b)^{2},(1+a)(1+b),(1-a)(1-b) \right \}=
\max \left \{ a^2,1-a^2 \right \}.$$
Therefore the minimum over $[-1,1]$ is attained when $a^2=1-a^2$, i.e. at $a=\pm1/\sqrt{2}$, the value there is $1/2$. 
$$\min_{a,b \in [-1,1]} \max \left \{ \frac{1}{4}(a-b)^{2},(1+a)(1+b),(1-a)(1-b) \right \}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
P.S. Note that the two minimum points $(\pm 1/\sqrt{2},\mp 1/\sqrt{2})$ are placed at the intersections of the three colored graphs (which are not planes).

Comment: damn i thought that $\sqrt[3](a-b)^{3}} \neq (a-b)$ ...

Comment: I totally changed the question sorry haha

Comment: @RomainB Any further doubt?

Comment: Nope ! Thanks a lot